# Definition of uniform continuity

Tags: uniform-continuity

We proved the following theorem in class and I have a few questions:

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $f:[a,b]\times[c,d] \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Then the function
>
> \begin{align}
> I:[c,d] &\longrightarrow\, \mathbb{R}\\
> y\,\,\, &\longmapsto\, I(y) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y)\, dx
> \end{align}
>
> is continuous on the interval $[c,d]$.

First of all we start to say that the function is uniform continuous over the domain. I know that a continuous function is uniform continuous if the domain is closed and bounded. How can see on the theorem that it is in fact closed?

Then we write the following ( Definition of uniform continuity ):

$ \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \Longrightarrow
\mid \mid (h,k) \mid \mid < \delta \rightarrow \mid f(x+h,y+k) - f(x,y) \mid < \epsilon $

I know the definition of uniform continuity but I can't perfectly recognize it there. I guess the first part is the distance between h and k, but what are really those h and k?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "how can see on the theorem"? Do you want a proof of the fact that $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Besides, $\|(h,k)\|$ is *not* the distance between $h$ and $k$. It is the distance between $(h,k)$ and $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yes for the first question. Thank you for the explanation, I didn't knew that for that distance. And why is this definition equivalent to those we always see in our books? (... $ \mid x-y \mid < \delta \rightarrow \mid f(x)-f(y) \mid < \epsilon $

Comment: How do you define "closed subset"?

Comment: The complement is open?

Comment: If you want to use that as definition, let's go. Take $(x,y)\notin[a,b]\times[c,d]$. Then $x\notin[a,b]$ or $y\notin[c,d]$. If $x\notin[a,b]$, take $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap[a,b]=\emptyset$. Then $D\bigl((x,y),\varepsilon\bigr)\cap[a,b]\times[c,d]=\emptyset$, where $D\bigl((x,y),\varepsilon\bigr)$ is the open disk centered at $(x,y)$ with radius $\varepsilon$. If $y\notin[c,d]$, you do the same thing. This proves that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus[a,b]\times[c,d]$ is open.